# Parsing XML from webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, webbrowser-control

I need to parse a XML file (which is generated by PHP) from a webbrowser control as the page I am trying to parse requires cookies to track some things. When I use something like:

```
string xmlURL = "urltophpfile";    
XmlTextReader reader = null;
reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlUrl);
```

to parse it, cookies aren't enabled so I need to use a webbrowser control or something which will allow me to use cookies.

The problem I am having is that when I try to put the webbrowser text to a string (`string info = webBrowser2.DocumentText.ToString();` it gives the full source of the web page and therefore I can't parse it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can work this out please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `HttpWebRequest` and specify the `CookieContainer` property.

This URL has a good example of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

EDIT: To be clear, I mean use HttpWebRequest to fetch the XML, and then load the xml using `XmlTextReader.Create` with one of the overloads that supports a stream or direct string input.